# Sticky Footer Content Div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have managed to get my footer to stick at the bottom of the page using the below method:-

http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-ie8new.htm

But my #content div has a border on the left and right and I basically also want that to expand to same height as the #wrapper.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

problem resolved using -- http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-wide-header-footer2.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the border on the "wrapper" div which is based on the approach here [CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html)

Edit:

Move border from content to wrapper
For wrapper

```
#wrapper {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 174px auto 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 870px;
}
```

for header

```
#header {
    border-top: 0 solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 174px;
    position: relative;
    top: -174px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I also though the same but then the border will show over the header and footer...

Comment: I do not think that it will show over the footer, and as for the header try giving the header a padding:0 -1px; style to cover the wrapper borders on left and right. Edit: I was wrong about the header :( It is different layout than I thought

Comment: this is interfering with the sticky footer method

Comment: maybe you should reconsider your layout and make it as in the example I gave you.